# Bash incorrect behaviour if there is not space beetwen args and redirection

Tags: bash, command-line, io-redirection

I have an issue. 
I wrote a program where I have to validate some arguments passed with the command line (I am using `argv[]`) and to use a file redirected on stdin as input. 
The program works but I have issues if there is not space between the arguments and the redirection

```
as ./aout -s 30 20< ficso
```

is this normal? I thought the character `<` was reserved by the bash.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A number placed directly against a redirection operator like this turns it into a different redirection operator, in this case one that takes its input from FD 20 instead of FD 0.

Comment: @xax: just to be clear, FD in this context means File Descriptor.  For example, FD 0 is known as stdin (standard input), 1 is stdout (standard output) and 2 is stderr (standard error).  A common use of an FD is `2> err.txt` which redirects stderr to "err.txt" file.  The redirection `<` is actually `0<` but FD 0 is the default.

Comment: I see. I will try to handle this differently. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
20< filename
```

it means that instead of redirecting standard input (file descriptor 0) to the file, it should redirect file descriptor `20` to the file.

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Input)

> **3.6.1 Redirecting Input**
>
> Redirection of input causes the file whose name results from the expansion of *word* to be opened for reading on file descriptor *n*, or the standard input (file descriptor 0) if *n* is not specified.
>
> The general format for redirecting input is:
>
> ```
>   [n]<word
> ```